# Django-tastypie: doesn't save ToOneField

Tags: django, foreign-key-relationship, tastypie, bad-request

Cann't undersntand where is problem:

```
class PostResource(ModelResource):

    place   = fields.ToOneField(PlaceResource,  attribute='place')
    user    = fields.ToOneField(ProfileResource,attribute='profile')
    #action  = fields.ForeignKey(ActionResource, 'action')

    def hydrate(self, bundle):
    -------------------------
        bundle.data['place'] = _place
        bundle.data['user']  = qProfile.objects.get(user = bundle.request.user)
        return bundle


class ProfileResource(ModelResource):
    username    = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user', blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        queryset = qProfile.objects.all()
        excludes = ['token']
        resource_name = 'profile'

    def dehydrate_username(self, bundle):
        bundle.data['username'] = bundle.obj.user.username
        return bundle.obj.user.username

class UserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        excludes = ['email', 'password', 'is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser']
        resource_name = 'user'

class PostInfo(models.Model):
    user        = models.ForeignKey(qProfile, related_name="PostUser",    on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    text        = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    photos      = models.ForeignKey(PostPhoto, related_name="PostPhoto",    on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    place       = models.ForeignKey(PlaceInfo, related_name="PostPlace",    on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    action      = models.ForeignKey(ActionInfo, related_name="PostAction",    on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    date        = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

bundle.data['place'] saves properly, but can't save user. Even if i will set into bundle.data['user'] bundle.request.user and change user ForeinKey to UserResource problem still here. This hydrate returns me Bad Request when i uncomment this line or line with 'action' definition:

```
user    = fields.ToOneField(ProfileResource,attribute='profile')
```

Comment: btw: replace `ProfileResource.username` with `username = fields.CharField('user__username', blank=True, null=True)` and remove `dehydrate_username`

Comment: Show your request json

Comment: It says that i give for __init__ 4 arguments, until it wait for 3 maximum (in this replaced line). https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=1165860260138611&set=a.889101011147872.1073741828.100001439453635&type=3&theater